# Facebook login access dialog stucks after hiding app and opening again.

Tags: android, facebook, dialog

I am using FB SDK to run a login flow in my app.

When FB app is not installed everything is ok.

But when login flow goes through the FB app I noticed strange thing:

If I hide my app, when the dialog, which requests user permissions pop up,
 and open it again the dialog stucks and neither back button nor its own buttons do anything.

Looks like it loses focus.

[image]

Any ideas ?